# recover oracle db from datafile

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

We have oracle db which unfortunately we did'n make backup and all control files and other files except all data-files are damaged. Is there any solution to recover db from all of these intact data-files? Thank you for helping me.

Comment: What about redo files?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link describing and solving the same problem, do note that you still have to make your own pfile, but that isn't hard.
http://myracle.wordpress.com/2008/01/11/recover-database-without-control-files-and-redo-log-files/